# Django Rest Framework invalid username/password

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

Trying to do a simple '**GET**' wih admin credentials returns

> "detail": "Invalid username/password."

I have a *custom user model* where I deleted the **username**, instead I use **facebook_id** :

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'facebook_id'
```

---

I tried changing the *DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES*:

```
('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',), -- doesn't work!
('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',), -- doesn't work!
```

The only one that works is:

```
('rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',),
```

But I do not want that, since I'm building an API for a Mobile App

I also declared a *CustomUserAdmin* model and *CustomUserCreationForm* , apparently this was not the problem

---

Help me understand what needs to be done to fix this annoying problem, I'm guessing it might have something to do with **Permissions/Authentication** or the fact that I CustomUserModel..

Also, let me know if there is a better way for a mobile app client to authenticate to the api

Answer (score 9):

Have just had the same problem. In my case the source of the problem was Apache's Basic Authentication, my browser was sending `Authorization` header and Django REST Framework thought that this header was to be handled by it. The solution is pretty simple: just remove
`'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'` from your

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [ 
        # ... auth classes here ... 
    ]
}
```

Or explicitly set the default `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` to remove `BasicAuth` from [DRF's defaults](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#default_authentication_classes).

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the default, and then you have per view.  You can set the default to `IsAuthenticated`, and then you override your view's particular `permission_classes`. e.g.

```
class ObtainJSONWebLogin(APIView):
    permission_classes = ()
```

or

```
class Foo(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = ()
```